# I am trying to get all employee positions (relationship many-to-many)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm a beginner. I try to get all the positions of the employee, but only the position of the first employee is returned. Employees and positions relationship is many-to-many. Whatever you do, the result is the same :(

View Model

```
public class DivisionEmployeeViewModel
{
    public DivisionEmployee DivisionEmployees { get; set; }
    public Division Division { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DivisionEmployee> DivisionEmployeeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EmployeePosition> EmployeePositionList { get; set; } // get 1 obj

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DivisionEmployeeListDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

Action Details

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
    {
        var model = new DivisionEmployeeViewModel
        {
            DivisionEmployeeList = await _db.DivisionEmployeesModel.Include(x => x.Employee)
            .Include(x => x.Division).Where(x => x.Division_Id == id).ToListAsync(),

            // Get only 1 obj
            EmployeePositionList = await _db.EmployeePositions.Include(x => x.Position)
            .Include(x => x.Employee).Where(x => x.Employee_Id == id).ToListAsync(),
            //

            DivisionEmployees = new DivisionEmployee()
            {
                Division_Id = id
            },

            Division = await _db.Divisions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)
        };

        List<int> tempAssignedList = model.DivisionEmployeeList.Select(x => x.Employee_Id).ToList();
        List<int> tempAssignedList2 = model.EmployeePositionList.Select(x => x.Position_Id).ToList(); // ? Get only 1 obj

        // Get all items who's Id isn't in tempAuthorsAssignedList and tempCitiesAssignedList
        var tempList = await _db.Employees.Where(x => !tempAssignedList.Contains(x.Id)).Where(x => !tempAssignedList2.Contains(x.Id)).ToListAsync();

        model.DivisionEmployeeListDropDown = tempList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.FullName,
            Value = x.Id.ToString()
        });

        return View(model);
    }
```

Project GitHub https://github.com/ValencyJacob/DepartmentManagementApp-Many-to-Many

Comment: Your `Division_Id` and `Employee_Id` are both id in `Details(int id)`?And `tempAssignedList2` is a list of positionId,why you use `.Where(x => !tempAssignedList2.Contains(x.Id))` to compare employeeId with positionId?

Comment: Yiyi You Sry master, it's my bad. Now all working ;) Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your Division_Id and Employee_Id are both id in Details(int id)?And tempAssignedList2 is a list of positionId,why you use .Where(x => !tempAssignedList2.Contains(x.Id)) to compare employeeId with positionId? – **Yiyi You**